# How to init mvvmcross forms IoC in android job service to use registered services when app is close?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have job service in my mvvmcross android forms app which is checking data from server and create new notification if is new post. Code for checking new posts is in service so i have to init mvvmcross IoC but i'm getting error then.

```
 [Service(Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
    public class NotificationJobService : JobService
        {
            private static readonly string TAG = "ExampleJobService";

            public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters args)
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "on start job: " + args.JobId);

                DoBackgroundWork(args);

                return true;
            }

            public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters args)
            {
                return true;
            }

            private void DoBackgroundWork(JobParameters args)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(ApplicationContext);
                    setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();

                    Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<INotificationService>().ShowNewPostNotification(new Newsfeed());

                    JobFinished(args, true);

                }).Start();
            }     
        }


    [Activity(Label = "SurrenderAt20", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", NoHistory = false, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<AndroidSetup, CoreApp, App>
    {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {        
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        StartJob();
    }

    void StartJob()
    {
        Class javaClass = Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationJobService));
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, javaClass);

        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
           .SetMinimumLatency(20000)
           .SetOverrideDeadline(25000)
           .SetPersisted(true)
           .Build();


        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
        int result = jobScheduler.Schedule(info);
        if (result == JobScheduler.ResultSuccess)
        {
            Log.Info("MainActivity", "Job Sheduled");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Info("MainActivity", "Job Filed Sheduled");
        }
    }
}

public sealed class AndroidSetup : MvxFormsAndroidSetup<CoreApp, App>
{       
    protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IOperatingSystemService), new OperatingSystemService()); 
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMasterDetailService), new MasterDetailService());       
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(typeof(INotificationService), new NotificationService());       
        Mvx.IoCProvider.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart, MvxAppStart<RootPageViewModel>>();

        base.InitializeLastChance(); //TODO remove (check if work)
    }
}
```

> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to create setup instance
>   ---> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not find a Setup class for application   at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupExtensions.CreateSetup[TSetup] () [0x00019] in
>   <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.Instance () [0x00015] in
>   <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.CreateSetup () [0x00000] in
>   <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.CreateSetup ()
>   [0x00017] in <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable[TMvxSetupSingleton]
>   () [0x00045] in <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0    at
>   MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable
>   (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x00000] in
>   <904768743fbc44a983fee28742390539>:0    at
>   Surrender_20.Forms.Services.NotificationJobService+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0
>   () [0x0000b] in <3bf0784f2f454fc395358149cf734980>:0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object
>   state) [0x00014] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   [0x0002b] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in
>   :0

Comment: Looking at the Mvvmcross source code, it seems that Mvvmcross tries to CreateSetup by using reflection. It is looking for a class with Name: "Setup" which is usually the convention for the setup class name. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetupExtensions.cs. Can you try renaming your setup class to "Setup" and try again?

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad to help, I will post it as an answer so others can be helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question originally answered in the comment and posting as an answer in the hopes to help others.

By convention, your setup class must be named "Setup" so you will need to rename `AndroidSetup` to `Setup`

Background: looking at the Mvvmcross [source code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetupExtensions.cs), the initialization logic uses reflection and convention to initialize itself.  It is looking for a class with name: "Setup". In your case, MvvmCross couldn't locate your setup class and threw the exception you read in the stack trace `MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not find a Setup class for application`